# Shut down a CURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to retrieve some data from an API using CURL request. Is it possible to track the time passed from request start and stop the request after sometime, may be less then the timeout set to it?

**NOTE:**

My aim is to not set timeout. Let the request continue until another job/function call don't arise. Is it possible?

**In Detail:**

What I exactly want is that, I have a function that call through Ajax and then a CURL start, and another Ajax will also call that function with some specific parameter, when second ajax call happen then the execution of CURL should stop. But the time interval within these two call is arbitrary.

Comment: Er, wouldn't what you described be... a timeout?

Comment: Why not just set timeout to the value you want

Comment: @Amber My aim is to not set timeout. Let the request continue until another job/function call don't arise. Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly would such other job be?! PHP is not multithreaded and also one long-running request won't block other requests.

Comment: @ThiefMaster yes i want something like that. if php is not multithreaded then is there any alternative?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThiefMaster what I exactly want is that, I have a function that call through Ajax and then a CURL start, and another Ajax will also call that function with some specific parameter, when second ajax call happen then the execution of CURL should stop. But the time interval within these two call is arbitrary.

Comment: @ThiefMaster hello sir, any luck for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I exactly want is that, I have a function that call through Ajax and then a CURL start, and another Ajax will also call that function with some specific parameter, when second ajax call happen then the execution of CURL should stop

Then you need to do that in your JavaScript code. Simply `.abort()` the previous AJAX request before sending a new one.

Comment: @ThierMaster but i think abort may stop the ajax but how can it stop the continuing curl request in php??

Comment: Unless you used `ignore_user_abort()` in PHP, aborting the request should abort the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can define that by setting `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` options of cURL transfer ([php doc](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php))

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are using to determine when enough is enough, but the following will stop a curl download in it's tracks:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, array($ch, "downloader"));
```

`downloader` just being a random function name, it takes the curl resource and the function name to pass the received input for saving.  It has to return the length received, or the connection aborts, so if you *didn't* want that to happen, you'd have the following:

```
function downloader($curlHandle,$data)
         {
            $data_string .= $data; // Store your data for later.
            $data_length = strlen($data); // Get length of current chunk
            return $data_length;  // pass it back and keep going.
          }
```

Now, hypothetically, if you had a global variable that indicated "Stop curl!"  you could return a false size and abort the transfer. Something like:

```
function downloader($curlHandle,$data)
         {
            $data_string .= $data; // Store your data for later.
            $data_length = strlen($data); // Get length of current chunk
            global $stop_curl;
            return ($stop_curl) ? "" : $data_length;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use **CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT** and **CURLOPT_TIMEOUT** for setting cURL options via [curl_setopt()](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt) function as follows:

```
<?php

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.
// Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

// The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10)

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple way to getting script execution time in PHP like that:

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($utime, $time) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$utime + (float)$time);
}

$script_start = microtime_float();
// here your curl request start
....

// here your curl request stop
$script_end = microtime_float();

echo "Script executed in ".bcsub($script_end, $script_start, 4)." seconds.";
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question at all.